# Checking if a remote server is online

Tags: vbscript

I have this vbs file to check if a remote server is accessible. Can I simplify or refactor to make it more robust/efficient?

```
const forReading = 1, forWriting = 2, forAppending = 8 
public maxWaitTime
maxWaitTime = 60 '1800 '30mins
public connLogFileName
connLogFileName = "connectionLog.txt"
public pathToRemoteServer 
pathToRemoteServer = "c:\"
public errMessage
public fs
set fs = createObject("scripting.fileSystemObject")

pathToRemoteServer = "c:\"

'::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
call mainSub()

'::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sub mainSub()
  call createLogFile()

  errMessage = ""
  dim curDir
  curDir = fs.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
  dim logName
  logName = curDir & "\" & connLogFileName 
  Dim aFile
  set aFile = fs.openTextFile(logName, forAppending, True)

  if (checkFolderPath(pathToRemoteServer)) then
    aFile.WriteLine lineToWrite & " ok"
  else 
    aFile.WriteLine lineToWrite & " " & errMessage  

    dim downTime
    downTime = 0
    do Until (checkFolderPath(pathToRemoteServer)) or downTime => maxWaitTime 
      WScript.Sleep 500  'half second
      downTime = downTime + 0.5
    loop

    aFile.WriteLine lineToWrite & " back after seconds: " & downTime     

  end if

  aFile.close
  if not aFile is nothing then set aFile = nothing
end sub

'::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sub createLogFile()
  dim logName
  logName = fs.GetAbsolutePathName(".") & "\" & connLogFileName 
  If not fs.FileExists(logName) Then
    fs.createTextFile logName, false
  End If
end sub 

':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
function lineToWrite()
  dim curUser
  curUser = createObject("WScript.Network").userName
  lineToWrite = curUser & ": " & Now()     '& vbCrLf
end function

':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
function checkFolderPath(folder_path) 
  checkFolderPath = false
  On Error Resume Next

  dim fn
  fn = folder_path & "testfile." & myDateFormat(Now())

  dim aFile   
  set aFile = fs.createTextFile(fn, True)
  if err.Number <> 0 Then
    errMessage = "Error on crt: " & err.description
    err.clear
    checkFolderPath = false
    exit function
  end if

  aFile.WriteLine ("This is a test file " & fn) 
  if err.Number <> 0 Then
    errMessage = "Error on wrt: " & err.description
    err.clear
    checkFolderPath = false
    exit function
  end if

  aFile.Close 
  if err.Number <> 0 Then
    errMessage = "Error on cls: " & err.description
    err.clear
    checkFolderPath = false
    exit function
  end if    

  fs.DeleteFile fn 
  if err.Number <> 0 Then
    errMessage = "Error on del: " & err.description
    err.clear
    checkFolderPath = false
    exit function
  end if 

checkFolderPath = true
if not aFile is nothing then set aFile = nothing
end function

':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
function myDateFormat(aDate)
  sc = second(aDate)
  mn = minute(aDate)
  hr = hour(aDate)
  dy = day(aDate)
  mt = month(aDate)    
  yr = year(aDate)
  myDateFormat= yr & mt & dy & hr & mn & sc
end function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot to cover and talk about here. I'm going to take a line by line approach, so this review might seem nitpicky (and it probably *is*), but there are some seemingly innocuous things here that can cause bigger problems given a chance.

---

> ```
> const forReading = 1, forWriting = 2, forAppending = 8
> ```

This is good. I like well named constants. These are implicitly Public though. That means they're available to all scripts. Which is also okay. I see no reason these can't be, but it's always better to be explicit and declare the scope.

```
Public Const forReading = 1, forWriting = 2, forAppending = 8
```

---

> ```
> public maxWaitTime
> maxWaitTime = 60 '1800 '30mins
> public connLogFileName
> connLogFileName = "connectionLog.txt"
> ```

Neither of these should be Public. Nor should they be variables. They're constants and should be declared as such. Let the compiler warn you if you ever try to assign a new value to these.

---

> ```
> public pathToRemoteServer 
> pathToRemoteServer = "c:\"
> public errMessage
> public fs
> set fs = createObject("scripting.fileSystemObject")
>
> pathToRemoteServer = "c:\"
>
> '::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
> ```

Same advice here. These variables should be private to the script. Also, you're reassigning the same value to the same variable just a few lines apart?? Make it a constant and forget it.

I try not to pick on names, but `fs` would be better named `fso`. The latter seems to be an idiom in the community. Generally, I don't recommend overly abbreviated names like this, but *idioms are ok*. VBA/VBScript developers will recognize both of these as a `FileSystemObject`.

---

> ```
> '::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
> call mainSub()
>
> '::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
> sub mainSub()
> ```

Two things jump out at me here.

1. `mainSub` isn't a good name. It doesn't say anything at all about what the subroutine does.
2. It doesn't seem to make much sense to have a subroutine here at all. You could remove the `Sub...End Sub` statement and just execute it in your main script without changing the semantics or execution at all. (I don't recommend actually doing that, but I'm not quite there yet.)

---

> ```
> sub mainSub()
>   call createLogFile()
>
>   errMessage = ""
>   dim curDir
>   curDir = fs.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
>   dim logName
>   logName = curDir & "\" & connLogFileName
> ' ....
> End Sub
>
> '::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
> sub createLogFile()
>   dim logName
>   logName = fs.GetAbsolutePathName(".") & "\" & connLogFileName 
>   If not fs.FileExists(logName) Then
>     fs.createTextFile logName, false
>   End If
> end sub
> ```

So, you're going to your file system object to get the current directory twice in rapid succession and sharing a variable between these two methods. That's smelly to me. `createLogFile` should take in a full file path as an argument. Then, `connLogFileName` doesn't need to be scoped outside of `mainSub`. Actually, I don't see a need for that constant at all in this case. You can keep it if you want, but I've removed it below.

```
sub createLogFile(logName)
  If not fs.FileExists(logName) Then
    fs.createTextFile logName, false
  End If
end sub 

sub mainSub()

  errMessage = ""

  dim logName
  logName = fs.GetAbsolutePathName(".") & "\" & "connectionLog.txt"

  call createLogFile(logName)

  Dim aFile
  set aFile = fs.openTextFile(logName, forAppending, True)
```

I also think it would be worthwhile to pass `pathToRemoteServer` into `mainSub` as an argument. It makes the sub more re-usable, but I would *definitely* think up a decent name for it.

---

I would rename `checkFolderPath`. Consider this snippet.

> ```
>  if (checkFolderPath(pathToRemoteServer)) then
> ```

Wouldn't it read better as:

```
if (folderPathExists(pathToRemoteServer)) then
```

Speaking of method names, I really recommend `PascalCased` method names. It distinguishes them from `camelCased` variable names.

---

I'm surprised this compiles.

> ```
> downTime => maxWaitTime
> ```

In VBA this results in a compiler error and it's expected to be `downTime >= maxWaitTime`. Perhaps VBScript is more forgiving, but it also looks like the lambda operator from another popular Microsoft language. So two things happen here. I can't paste this into the VBA Editor and run it and it could cause confusion for someone expecting this to be the lambda operator.

---

> ```
> ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
> function lineToWrite()
>   dim curUser
>   curUser = createObject("WScript.Network").userName
>   lineToWrite = curUser & ": " & Now()     '& vbCrLf
> end function
> ```

I like this function and the abstraction it provides, but you are calling it over and over and over to get the same string. Declare a variable and call this function once. Also, as an option, It would be completely acceptable to remove the `curUser` variable and one line this function.

```
Function LineToWrite()

    LineToWrite = CreateObject("WScript.Network").userName & ": " & Now()  

End Function
```

Also, you should remove dead, commented out code. It serves no purpose but to clutter things.

---

One last thing. Your error messages kind of suck. It's one thing to abbreviate variable names, but it's an entire other matter to abbreviate error/log messages.

> ```
> errMessage = "Error on crt: " & err.description 
> errMessage = "Error on cls: " & err.description 
> errMessage = "Error on del: " & err.description
> ```

Don't do that. Spell it out for whoever has to read that log.

It's also noteworthy that there's a lot of copy paste in the `CheckFolderPath` function, as evidence by the snippet above. It's wholly worth while to extract that logic into a function that takes an `Err` object and a string in as arguments.

Comment: just taking a break from my "proper" work to head back to this script: your comments could not have been timed better!

Comment: Happy to help. I'm only sorry I don't know of an actual better way to go about what you're doing.

Comment: "A better way" ... this way is fun, at least it is for me (as mainly play with mdx/sql/vba)

Comment: (no need to worry about lambda functions ... not many people in our office will have even heard of them!)

Comment: I've used the `>` in `downTime => maxWaitTime` deliberately in case someone incremets by something other than 0.5 so don't really understand this criticism

Comment: You're right about the loop. I removed that bit. My bad. I must have been [smoking the documentation](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1953/41243)

Comment: I've implemented changes and am testing. If I open the file "connectionLog.txt" to check out the logs I get an error as the running program wants to write to it ....where do add the error trapping to avoid this?

Comment: You could do it in `mainSub` if you like. It's hard for me to say without seeing it, but all untrapped errors would bubble up into there. If you're still having trouble implementing changes, I recommend asking a question on StackOverflow.